# When using docker-compose to fire up containers how do I programatically get their ips?

Tags: docker, travis-ci, docker-compose

In my travis-ci I am using scripts to call up my docker containers one by one. I am planning to replace these with a `docker-compose` yml file which can do this faster and cleaner.

I cannot figure out however how to replace this part of my script:

```
- CID=$(docker run --privileged --detach --volume="${PWD}":/root/django_deployment:rw -p 80 --name test_centos censofdockers/centos6-miniconda sleep 550) 
- CID2=$(docker run --privileged --detach --volume="${PWD}":/root/django_deployment:rw -p 80 --name test_ubuntu censofdockers/ubuntu-miniconda sleep 550)
- DOCKER_IP=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' ${CID}`
- DOCKER_IP2=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' ${CID2}`
```

If I use docker-compose how can I programmatic-ally find out what the ips of the individual containers are ?

Comment: for what do you need the ip addresses after you launched the docker containers with docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following as `~/.local/bin/docker-ip` to get the ip address of a container.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker inspect -f \
    '{{range $key, $value := .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{ $value.IPAddress}} {{end}}' $1
```

To use this with a container created by compose use `<project name>_<service name>` as the container name.

```
docker-ip <CID or container name>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in your Compose YAML by giving the containers an explicit `container_name`:

```
ub1:
    image: ubuntu
    command: ping localhost
    container_name: ub1

ub2:
   image: ubuntu
   command: ping localhost
   container_name: ub2
```

Then when you `docker-compose up` the application, the containers will have a known name and you can inspect them using that:

```
> docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' ub1
172.18.0.2
> docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' ub2
172.18.0.3
```

**Note:** using `container_name` means Compose will only let you have one instance of the container, so you can't use `scale`, but in your scenario that doesn't look like an issue.

Alternatively you can [specify an explicit IP address](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ipv4-address-ipv6-address) for your containers in the Compose file.

Comment: What version of docker allows you to inspect by name ? Mine does not have that function. Using docker version that comes with Ubuntu: 1.11.2

Comment: What I found works with my version is something like this: `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -aqf "name=ranky_panini")`

Comment: It's not new - just tried it on Engine 1.10.1 and it works in the same way.